# How many journalists have been killed in two currently pending conflicts?

Tags: media, human-rights, war-crime

Currently, two wars in the world have attracted the attention of the media: the war between *Russia and Ukraine* (within about two years), and the war between *Israel and Palestine* (within about 100 days). Many people have been killed. But this question is about *journalists*.

How many journalists have been killed by *Russia* (within two years)?
How many journalists have been killed by *Ukraine* (within two years)?
How many journalists have been killed by *Israel* (within 100 days)?
How many journalists have been killed by *Palestine* (within 100 days)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has no lasting value - it's a point in time snapshot.  3yrs from now, 
it will have no meaning.  Furthermore it presupposes clear attribution.  And it looks a tad calculated to make some parties look worse than others.

Comment: See https://rsf.org/en/barometer

Comment: @Italian Philosophers This question  **has** lasting value, because it compares 4 sides war crimes against journalist, in a certain period of time.

Comment: @user1 The fact that a journalist dies while covering a war doesn't inherently make it a war crime (often, maybe usually, it wouldn't be a war crime), but I do agree that the number of journalist deaths in a discrete time period is potentially relevant to political issues (albeit, hard to determine accurately), since it provides context for how important and common an issue might be.

Comment: @ohwilleke I agree with most part of your comment. but If the number of journalists killed by one side is significantly different from the other sides, the issue of war crimes will not be meaningless

Comment: @user1 The issue of war crimes isn't meaningless. It simply isn't the question asked (and is a much harder one to determine the answer to). War zones are dangerous places and there are lots of ways to be killed there without war crimes being committed and lots of reasons for this to be one sides without war crimes being at issue (e.g. the Russia-Ukraine war is being fought in Ukraine not Russia, and the Israel-Gaza conflict is being mostly fought after Oct 7-8, in Gaza not Israel). Also, it is fair to note that often a journalist dies and it isn't clear that one side or the other killed them.

Comment: @user1 For example, if a journalist dies in a car accident, or from rubble from a building that was struck days earlier, or by a civilian who mistakes them for a bandit, or at the hands of a bandit, neither side killed the journalist, and if the journalist is embedded with (or just physically close to) a military unit that is targeted and killed as collateral damage, or steps on a mine in a mine field, it isn't a war crime. To be a war crime, at a minimum, the person must be known to be a journalist (or at least an unarmed civilian) and targeted anyway.

Comment: @user1 What ohwilleke said about the dangers of war zones.  I am not discounting Israel's problems with journalists.  For example, IIRC I voted to reopen a question about Shireen Abu Akleh (which I can't find now).  But where combats are taking place and how concentrated they are *will* impact the number of journalists killed.  Let's flip this around:  suppose someone asked "what what was the biggest count in a single day of civilians killed at close range in Gaza/Israel vs Ukraine/Russia?"  Do you think that question should remain open?  I don't and I'd vote to close.

Comment: Taking the entirey of one war while rejecting a majority of the other, and with no relative measurement of terrirotry or forces involved to scale them appropriately, this question can only be intended to push a political position that one of these four groups is killing far more journalists than the others.

Comment: @ohwilleke If the landmine was an an antipersonnel device and laid by Ukrainian forces, there might be issues around the Ottawa treaty, which might not be a technical war crime, but would certainly be in the spirit (and possibly reporting).

Comment: Such a topic is recorded by organisations like Reporters Without Borders and widely discussed in the media, so it seems a reasonable question. Main criticism would be that it's too trivial and possibly posted to make a political point, but being easily googlable or lacking in even the most cursory research isn't grounds for deletion on Politics SE.

Comment: Voting to reopen - the deliberate killing of journalists are definitely political moves to prevent the dissemination of information. While it can be hard to ascertain if a journalist has been deliberately targeted and killed, the question doesn't ask about this and simply asks for the number of journalists killed. This can be factually answered as these deaths are recorded by licensed media outlets and other organisations.

Comment: @sfxedit It's not trivial, but it is obviously posted to make a point.  And I bet the answers will come from people making a point too. And then there will be an argument.  This makes such questions very tiresome.

Comment: @JamesK I have made my stance on this clear many times in my review comments and in Meta - it is a waste of time trying to figure out whether a post is meant to be a "propaganda" because (1) anyone with a different political view on a political issue can find a "propaganda" in every Q on it (and they do, as we reviewers are well aware of it) (2) unless some of us are mind-readers, everyone is making a best guess *assumption* of the questioner's intention (which is disrespectful) and (3) even if a Q is an meant for propaganda it will (eventually) be countered by someone as the community grows.

Comment: @JamesK But 3 can happen only if the moderators of this SE recognize that this as an SE meant to discuss political views *academically*, and actually allow *different* political views to find space here. And rules are enforced *uniformly* for all without bias. Honestly, that is not happening here - I feel less and less inclined to participate here since I realised Po.SE is meant to be just another "echo chamber" on the internet.

Comment: There are more than 2:  [Lost of ongoing armed conflicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ongoing_armed_conflicts)

Comment: @RogerV. The question never said there weren't, only that these two have attracted the most attention, which is undeniably true (they, for example, have their own sections on the BBC News website).

Comment: This question should really specify a date range for the deaths as with the current past 100 days requirement the number will change from day to day.

Comment: In addition to this being a push-question trying to prove a point, these are 4 different questions in one. A question should ask one question only.

Comment: For this question to be on topic it needs to explain the relation between the 4 different questions

Answer (score 7):

In accordance with [CPJ](https://cpj.org/) (Commitee to Protect Journalists) database, up to the beginning of 2024, the same number has been killed in both Ukraine and Gaza conflicts:

- [37](https://cpj.org/data/killed/europe/ukraine/?status=Killed&motiveConfirmed%5B%5D=Confirmed&motiveUnconfirmed%5B%5D=Unconfirmed&type%5B%5D=Journalist&type%5B%5D=Media%20Worker&cc_fips%5B%5D=UP&start_year=1992&end_year=2024&group_by=location) journalists and media workers have been killed in Ukraine war. Journalists [are not allowed](https://theintercept.com/2023/06/22/ukraine-war-journalists-press-credentials/) to the front line in Ukraine, some still go there. Still, this restriction results less of them being killed.
- [None](https://cpj.org/data/killed/?status=Killed&motiveConfirmed%5B%5D=Confirmed&motiveUnconfirmed%5B%5D=Unconfirmed&type%5B%5D=Journalist&type%5B%5D=Media%20Worker&cc_fips%5B%5D=RS&start_year=2022&end_year=2024&group_by=year) in Russia during the recent two years ([Vladlen Tatarsky](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-68095875)  did not make into the list but he was more a blogger). (this answer assumes borders of Russia as internationally recognized). Unwanted journalists may be arrested and jailed but not just killed so far.
- [37](https://cpj.org/full-coverage-israel-gaza-war/) killed in the recent Israel - Gaza war (not exactly that the question asks but somewhat relevant).
- [75](https://cpj.org/data/killed/?status=Killed&motiveConfirmed%5B%5D=Confirmed&motiveUnconfirmed%5B%5D=Unconfirmed&type%5B%5D=Journalist&type%5B%5D=Media%20Worker&cc_fips%5B%5D=IS&start_year=2022&end_year=2024&group_by=year) have been killed during the recent two years in Israel and the Occupied Palestinian Territory together (unable to separate the data sets)

From these numbers, a work of journalist in Gaza is more dangerous.

Ukraine and Gaza wars have "natural" start dates. Otherwise the data range for this query was 2022-2024 as 2024 now just begins (one month only).

Comment: A good attempt to answer an a balanced way, but this does not answer the question which emphasises "By Russia", not "In Russia".

Comment: It was a Russian girl...

Comment: @JamesK The answer requested by the question might not be possible to determine by any means short of inquests into each specific death. Lots of deaths can be attributable to neither party. This answer does, however, put an upper bound on the maximum number of journalist deaths in each conflict, so it also places an upper bound the the number of deaths caused by either side. (Also, of course, the fact that one side or the other kills a journalist does not, itself, mean that the death was because someone was a journalist in a manner amounting to a war crime.)

Comment: It's not exactly true that journalists are not allowed on the front line in Ukraine. There are some of those reports. The might not be regularly allowed, and they were surely not allowed while Ukraine was preparing its offensive this summer, but that's a little different.

Comment: And the claim about Russia doesn't mean no Russian journalists have been killed. Some were killed while reporting from the occupied territories, but that doesn't count as Russia in CJP's stats.

Comment: Random example(s) of reporting from the front line in Ukraine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhrZZG2H8Wg ; https://youtu.be/tH_lNnRDkGM?t=573 -- the latter is recent, so clearly the prohibition doesn't apply [anymore].

Comment: Actually, CPJ doesn't include any Russians at all among their statistics for Ukraine. They probably don't consider workers for Rossiya 24 etc. "proper" journalists... even though the EFJ does https://europeanjournalists.org/blog/2023/07/24/ukraine-russian-journalist-killed-in-shelling/

Comment: EFJ is not consistent though. They did not report the death of this guy (t Boris Maksudov): https://twitter.com/ian_matveev/status/1727596463591485922

Comment: @Fizz I made some clarifications